# Span tag inside anchor tag styling issue

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with a particular aspect of a web dev that I am doing at the moment with regards the css styling.

What I have is the following HTML:

```
<div id = "spaninsidea">
 <ul id="spantest">
    <li><a id="nav-button-one"  href="javascript:return false;"><span>Link 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a id="nav-button-two"  href="javascript:return false;"><span>Link 2</span></a></li>
</div>
```

Styled with the following CSS:

```
#spaninsidea { background: #494949; padding: 5px 5px 5px 37px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0 0 10px 0; }
#spaninsidea li { display: inline;}
#spaninsidea li a { text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center; border-radius:5px; 
display: block; margin-right:50px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;
float: left; }
#spaninsidea li a span {background-color:orange; margin-top:50px}
```

What I am trying to get is the spaned text inside the link to sit in the middle of the a tag. When I try to apply the margin setting on the span it simply sits still, however if I change the font color etc it plays cricket. I cant figure why it styles but wont budge.

I will confess the front end stuff is new to me so if there are any glaring issues that you can see in general please do point them out.

Cheers

Comment: I think you just want to set left & right margin to auto on your span and you'll be good to go - would be easier if you set up a jsfiddle.

Comment: @BethBudwig margins don't apply on inline level elements. And the spans are useless in this context.

Comment: @RikudoSennin any suggestions then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you shouldn't have a `span` within an `a`. That would be the first part... I would suggest try to apply a `text-align:center;` to the `span` as well.

**Update:** See a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/2eLer/ You just have to set the `line-height` of the `span` equal to or greater than the height of the `a`.

Comment: In this case, a `span` is unnecessary, but in general there is no reason "you shouldn't have a `span` within an `a`." It is perfectly valid and is often needed for intricately styled links.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock - That has worked a treat. Can you explain why not to lace the span, essentially I want to get the central text in the a tag but am wanting to get it done the right way?!?

Comment: You can use the span tag if need be, but I have it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nAe7G/1/ without it but keeping the look. It does, however, all depend on what you want to do with.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember that spans are inline elements not block elements and as such, do not respond to margin and padding like you would think they do.

There is a css display property called "inline-block" that allows elements to float like spans and other inline elements do, but also makes them behave like divs with regards to margin and padding.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `<span>` at all, but change the `padding` property of the link itself.